# Passing form data inside html table to controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm new to laravel, and I want to pass array data from html table to controller

I have tried using this code

Controller

```php
foreach($request->input('chk', []) as $key => $chk){
   $att = new Attendance;
   $att->student_id = $key;
   $att->date = $request->att_day;
   $status = $chk == 'true' ? 1 : 0;
   $att->status = $status;

}
```

View

```php
<form action="{{route('attendance.save')}}" method="post" class="form-horizontal form-bordered">
<table class="table">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="text-center">#</th>
         <th>Student Name</th>
         <th>Status</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
   @foreach ($students as $key => $s)
      <tr>
         <td class="text-center">{{ $key + 1 }}</td>
         <td>{{ $s->student_name }}</td>
         <td>
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-primary">
               <input type="radio" id="rdo_{{$key}}_pre" name="rdo[{{$s->id}}]" class="custom-control-input" checked>
               <label class="custom-control-label" for="rdo_{{$key}}_pre">Present</label>
            </div>
            <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-pink">
               <input type="radio" id="rdo_{{$key}}_abs" name="rdo[{{$s->id}}]" class="custom-control-input">
               <label class="custom-control-label" for="rdo_{{$key}}_abs">Absent</label>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   @endforeach
   </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

When I check the data passed to the controller, it is all [0](/questions/tagged/0) or [1](/questions/tagged/1) according to the first data in the table. How to get the rdo value as selected in the view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add a value attribute to each input to denote what was checked exactly.

```
<td>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-primary">
        <input type="radio" id="rdo_{{$key}}_pre" name="rdo[{{$s->id}}]" class="custom-control-input" value="present" checked>
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="rdo_{{$key}}_pre">Present</label>
    </div>
    <div class="custom-control custom-radio radio-pink">
        <input type="radio" id="rdo_{{$key}}_abs" name="rdo[{{$s->id}}]" class="custom-control-input" value="absent">
        <label class="custom-control-label" for="rdo_{{$key}}_abs">Absent</label>
    </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `foreach($request->input('chk', []) as $key => $chk)` to `foreach($request->input('rdo') as $key => $chk)`?

Comment: Why would this work? The second argument to `input()` is just the default if it's not present; what's the reason for omitting it, and why do you think this answers the question being asked?